# Will std::experimental::optional<> support references?

Tags: c++, std, c++17

At the moment, `boost::optional<>` supports references but the `std::experimental::optional<>` on my system from libstdc++ does not. Is this reflective of what might make it into the standard?

I know that the optional proposal author spun off optional references as a separate proposal so that the main optional proposal would have a better chance of being accepted. Was the proposal for optional references rejected or did work on it stop?

Comment: One can always use `std::reference_wrapper`. Supporting "raw" references would open a whole dimention of possibilities for shooting oneself into the foot.

Comment: @bobah I'd mention your comment in my answer. Is it fine for you?

Comment: @skypjack - sure :-)

Comment: @bobah Good suggestion. Is there a reason optional references are more likely to end up dangling than regular references? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @Praceolitic - it is not as easy to unintentionally stick a reference wrapper to a container as plain reference and it's unambiguous what to do when the container is assigned a value of type `T` or a value of type `reference_wrapper<T>()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this reflective of what might make it into the standard?

From the working draft ([[20.5.2/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional#optional.syn-1)):

> A program that necessitates the instantiation of template optional for a reference type [...] is ill-formed.

I guess this replies to your question.

Note that you can still work around it by using `std::reference_wrapper`, as mentioned by @bobah in the comments.