# Defining uninitilized reference c++

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, rvalue-reference

I have a template

```cpp
T template<typename T>undefined_behavior(void)
{
    throw;
    return T{};
}
template<typename T>
struct UBHandler
{
    const bool valid;
    T value;
    (operator T)()
    {if(valid)return value;return undefined_behavior<T>();}
};
```

This works when using rvalues but breaks when using rvalue references because—references aren't pointers and can't be constructed out of thin air.

`error: member ‘... ::value’ is uninitialized reference`

Before I wipe out all code relying on this and start over, is there a way to satisfy the compiler with some kind of null reference or magic uncorn—union thing?

Or something.

Undefined behavior welcome.

<del>This should work because std::optional exists and std::optional has rvalue reverence overloads?</del> sadness. Perhaps not, after reading previously asked questions. But it was proposed in 2014 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3982.html I have no idea how to interpret this into a solution.

<del>What is std::optional doing to get away with this that I'm missing?</del> Sadness.

I tried reading the following questions but I have no ideas.

- [Constraint on std::optional's forwarding reference constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966001/constraint-on-stdoptionals-forwarding-reference-constructor)
- [std::optional specialization for reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858034/stdoptional-specialization-for-reference-types)
- [Why GCC rejects std::optional for references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382838/why-gcc-rejects-stdoptional-for-references)
- [Will std::experimental::optional<> support references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905409/will-stdexperimentaloptional-support-references)
- [std::optional<T> call by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61096479/stdoptionalt-call-by-reference)

Comment: Well, given the shown code seems to be ill-formed (and no self-respecting C++ compiler will want to do anything here), any reply would be pure speculation, since your exact situation is unclear.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik
If I knew how to write a default constructor for null type it wouldn't be a question.
`UBHandler{false,?}` what could I possibly pass as an argument? There is nothing that I have yet found. Maybe a global void thing?

Comment: This has nothing to do with any constructor. Things like a missing semicolon, and referring to undeclared class names tend to throw a monkey wrench in asking questions here.

Comment: `is there a way to satisfy the compiler with some kind of null reference or magic uncorn—union thing?` So use a pointer? It's literally a reference that can be invalid by being a `nullopt`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I saw nullopt in my search and skipped over it. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems trivial to overload the type for references and write:

```
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
struct UBHandler
{
    const bool valid;
    T value;
    operator T() {
        if (valid) return value;
        throw std::runtime_error("");
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct UBHandler<T&>
{
    T *const value;
    UBHandler() : value(nullptr) {}
    UBHandler(T& value) : value(&value) {}
    operator T() {
        if (value) return *value;
        throw std::runtime_error("");
    }
};

int main() {
    UBHandler<int&> a;
    a + 1;
    int b = 1;
    int &c = b;
    UBHandler<int&> d{c};
    d + 1;
}
```